# Why I can't refer to the element just created in another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, null

I have two action functions here, the first one, `firstStartSlide()`, creates a div of `#2-slide` id and appends it to the document, the second one however `secondStartSlide()` just simply wants to refer to `#2-slide` and `console.log` it, but I have no idea why either 'null' or an empty object is returned when I attempt to refer to it inside another function!

I know I can refer to `#2-slide` inside the `firstStartSlide()` but I need to refer to that inside `secondStartSlide()`, but `secondStartSlide()` or any other function just doesn't recognize it,

anybody knows why this error is happening and how I can fix this?

```js
    const eachImageWidth = 700;
    const eachImageHeight = 360;

    let index = 1;

    //-----------------------------  DOM elements creator  -------------------------------
    function domElementsCreator(nth) {
        let slideWrapperContainer = document.querySelector('.main');
        let slide = document.querySelectorAll('.img-wrapper');
        let imgWrapper = document.createElement('div');
        imgWrapper.classList.add('img-wrapper');
        imgWrapper.id = `${nth}-slide`;
        $('.main').append(imgWrapper);
    }

    // ------------------- image creator function ---------------------
    function createImages(nth) {
        $(slideWrapperContainer).css('width', '700px').css('height', eachImageHeight);
        $(`#${nth}-slide`).css('width', '1400px');

        for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            let img = document.createElement('img');
            $(img).attr('src', `https://via.placeholder.com/700x360`);
            $(`#${nth}-slide`).append(img);
        }
    }

    domElementsCreator(1)

    slideWrapperContainer = document.querySelector('.main');
    slides = document.querySelectorAll('.img-wrapper img');
    slide = document.querySelectorAll('.img-wrapper');

    createImages(1)

    //----------------------  first sliding round  ------------------------
    function firstStartSlide(){
        index++;
        slide[0].style.transform = `translateX(${-eachImageWidth * (index - 1)}px)`;
        slide[0].style.transition = '1000ms';
        setTimeout(firstStartSlide, 1500);

        if (index === 4){
            domElementsCreator(2)
            createImages(2)
            $('#2-slide').css('left', '0').css('zIndex', '-1')
        }
    }
    firstStartSlide();

    //---------------------------  second round  -----------------------------
    function secondStartSlide() {
        let a = 1;
        //***************************  here is the error  **********************
        console.log($('#2-slide'))
        console.log(document.getElementById('2-slide'))
        //**********************************************************************
    }
    setTimeout(secondStartSlide, 2 * (1500));
```

```css
     *{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        /*---  slideWrapperContainer  ---*/
        .main{
            margin: 100px auto;
            border: 5px solid #000;
            position: relative;
            /*overflow: hidden;*/
        }

        /*-------  slideWrapper  ------*/
        .outer-img-wrapper{
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        /*----------  slide  ----------*/
        .img-wrapper{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bigContainer">
  <div class="main">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you calling `firstStartSlide` before the other functions? Is it successfully creating the element? A good place to start is the [chrome devtools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/)

Comment: There are two issues with your code: (1) `#` is not part of the ID, so it should be `document.getElementById('2-slide')`.  (2) `secondStartSlide` is called too early. It is called before the element was created.  If you fix the ID selector and increase  the timeout to `3 * 1500` then you will see the element logged to the console. However that should already be an indication that the whole approach is questionable. You shouldn't have to rely on the correct timing for your code to work.